# ¿Cómo ejecutar una tarea cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: java, android

Quisiera saber como hacer que se ejecute algo cada x segundos sin que la aplicación se torne lenta, por el momento tengo una manera con asynctask pero esta vuelve lenta la aplicación y en ocaciones hace que no responsa y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que esta no se torne lenta, algo que funcione como un thread quizás, que se ejecute en paralelo con la aplicación sin que esta se vea afectada

Comment: Si revisas el contenido del sitio podrás encontrar similares. Te recuerdo revisar nuevamente [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Creo que lo más optimo es utilizar el patrón de diseño Observer (o Listener), el cual permite notificar sobre el cambio en algún objeto. No conozco la estructura de tu base de datos pero quizá puedas hacer una implementación de un Listener que notifique el cambio de algún objeto dentro de la misma. Por ejemplo, Firebase utiliza onDataChangeListener, onChildEventListener para estar atento al cambio en referencias de la base.